# How to start Jenkins with a different user?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, jenkins, forever

I am working with Jenkins and I want to start a script with [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) using Jenkins with a different user named `aroot`.

So my build configuration I write this command:

```
sudo -u aroot forever start -a --uid 'server' bin/www
```

It works fine but `forever` still tries to access the `jenkins` user and when I try to see the scripts running under forever by using the command:

```
forever list
```

I see nothing. Why does this happen? I have changed the user to `aroot` but it still tries to start the script under `jenkins` user. What should I do here?

I even tried changing the default `jenkins` user to `aroot` but after this, the Jenkins just does not restart.

Answer (score 0):

you should not need the forever thing going. just enable it from `systemctl`

```
# systemctl enable jenkins.service
```

how you get it to run as different users is by editing this file.

```
# vi /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
```

and changing this line to whatever user you want.

```
JENKINS_USER="aroot"
```

When you restart it will be running as that user but you will need to `chown` all files in `/var/lib/jenkins` so it has the correct ownership.